Python 3.9.2: How to set pickle protocol 5?
I'm using a queue library that supports custom serializers for my application (https://github.com/alex-petrenko/faster-fifo).
My application transfers a lot of data, but using out-of-band memory locations is a little over my head at the moment. I did, however, find that maybe pickle protocol 5 will give some improvements anyway. I'd like to try this, but I'm not sure how to go about setting the pickle protocol when I'm not using it directly in my application, but the Queue library under the hood does.
Checking pickle.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL yields 4, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL is 5.
The custom serializer part of the library is invoked like this:
q = Queue(max_size_bytes=100000, loads=custom_deserializer, dumps=custom_serializer)
Question: Can I use the above to invoke loads and dumps with protocol 5 specificed? If yes, how?
